# MSI installer with page of selecting the language

Tags: wix

I want to create an installation package using WIX. I found that WIX cannot provide a multi-language installer, but only different installers with different code (local).

I found a description of how to integrate multiple language in one MSI using WIX and sole scripts from WINDOWS SDK. 
http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/index.htm

But what I want to have is a first interface to select the language from a list of all available languages​​. 
Does someone guide me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The language resources are loaded during msi initialization based on configuration. By the time you show a ui for language selection your language resources are already loaded. You will have to somehow update the configuration prior to initialization.

See this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423808/creating-language-selection-dialog-using-wix)